# How to go back to command line

Tags: python, command-line, read-eval-print-loop

after I type `python`
the SSH goes run python in command line. How to exit? I want to type new "SUDO" command but i can't exit python "mode".

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the Python interactive interpreter, also called the REPL (for "read-eval-print-loop") or Python shell. This Python documentation gives some details: [Using the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press **Ctrl + D** or type **exit()** in console to be able to exit Python's shell.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know what do you mean by python mode, but I suppose you are in python command line and you have this:

```
>>>
```

if so you can type `exit()` or `quit()` or press CTRL + D.

Answer (score 3):

You can either type in the command

```
exit()
```

or you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.
This will take you back.

Answer (score 3):

Give the console exit() should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `exit()`. It will exit python.